# Why is $\operatorname{rank}(A^* A)=\operatorname{rank}(A) \Leftrightarrow$ $(A^* Ax=0 \Leftrightarrow Ax=0)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A \in M_{m\times n}(F)$ and $x \in F^n$.

$A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$.

Why is $\operatorname{rank}(A^* A)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ equivalent to $A^* Ax=0$ if and only if $Ax=0$?

Comment: Is $F$ any field? Then what is $A^*$? No matter what, use the rank-nullity theorem. And note that the latter says $\ker A^*A=\ker A$.

Comment: @julien Yes, I tried to use that but still don't know how to connect $Nullity(A^* A)=Nullity(A)$ and $rank(A^* A)=rank(A)$.

Comment: What does the rank-nullity theorem say?

Comment: @julien I know that $rank(A^* A)=rank(A)$ is equivalent to $Nullity(A^* A)=Nullity(A)$ here. But from above equation, $A^* Ax=0$ and $Ax=0$, I'm a bit confused to find nullspace.

Comment: Please read the last sentence of my first comment again.

Comment: Hmm.. let me explain it my own way. From $Ax=0$, we can find nullspace and it can be applied to $A^* Ax=0$ too. So they have the same nullspace, thus their nullity is equal. Is that right?

Comment: $x\in\ker A\iff Ax=0\iff A^*Ax=0\iff  x\in \ker A^*A$. So $\ker A=\ker A^*A$.

Comment: @julien Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's missing for the OP in all this is the $\impliedby$. If $A^*Ax=0$, then $0=\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle = \langle Ax,Ax\rangle = \|Ax\|^2$.

Answer (score 4):

If $\operatorname{rank}(A^*A)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ it means $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n-\dim(\operatorname{null}(A))$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A^*A)=n-\dim(\operatorname{null}(A^*A))$ so   $\dim( \operatorname{null}(A))=\dim(\operatorname{null}(A^*A))$ if exist $x$ such that $Ax\ne 0$ and $A^*Ax=0$ then $x\in \operatorname{null}(A^*A)$but but $x$ not belong to $\operatorname{null}(A)$ and since $\operatorname{null}(A)\subset \operatorname{rank}(A^*A)$ so   $$\dim( \operatorname{null}(A))\ne \dim(\operatorname{null}(A^*A))$$contradiction!

on the other hand :
we know $\operatorname{null}(A)\subset \operatorname{null}(A^*A)$ in general

and since $A^*Ax=0$ if and only if $Ax=0$ it means $\operatorname{null}(A^*A)\subset \operatorname{null}(A)$ and so $\operatorname{null}(A^*A)=\operatorname{null}(A)$ and

So :
$\operatorname{rank}(A^*A)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$

Comment: :)  happy to you too .